# Couldn't save an Integer in a Object Array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I want to parse an String from an Object[] into an Integer and save it at the same place like this:

```
public class ArrParseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] arr = new Object[2];
        String  input = "Boo;Foo;1000";
        Integer somInt = new Integer(0);

        arr = input.split(";", -1);
        somInt = Integer.parseInt((String) arr[2]);

        arr[2] = somInt;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

but i receive allways this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Integer
    at main.ArrParseTest.main(ArrParseTest.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I don't understand why I can't simply save that parsed object into the array, I though that an

> Object[] arr = new Object[2];

is exactly made to store diffrent objects in an Array.

Anybody now how I can parse this String to an Integer and save it in the array??

Comment: `Object[] arr = new Object[2];` gives you an array with two places, `0` and `1`. So `arr[2] = somInt;` is going to be a bit of an issue, irrespective anything else...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the problem causing the immediate issue you're seeing:

```
arr = input.split(";", -1);
```

You're assigning a reference to an object of type `String[]` to a variable of type `Object[]`. That's fine, but it means you can't store non-string references in the array.

You probably want:

```
String input = "Boo;Foo;1000";
Integer someInt = new Integer(0);

String[] split = input.split(";", -1);
Object[] arr = new Object[split.length];
System.arraycopy(split, 0, arr, 0, split.length);
```

That will copy the contents of the `String[]` into an `Object[]` of the same size. You can then assign a new value to any element of the `Object[]`, and *that* new value can be an `Integer` reference.

It's not clear why you're initializing `someInt` to a value you ignore, by the way. Indeed, you don't even need the variable:

```
arr[2] = Integer.valueOf((String) arr[2]);
```

or

```
arr[2] = Integer.valueOf(split[2]);
```

Comment: I wanted to write clear code very easy to understand so I intialized these temporary variable

Comment: @Synoon: Clear code which is easy to understand would only declare a variable where it needed to, and wouldn't initialize it with a dummy value for so reason.

Comment: okey after your edit i have exactly the perfect solution for my problem thx!

Answer (score 1):

ArrayStoreException is Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects.

```
    Object[] arr = new Object[2];
    String  input = "Boo;Foo;1000";
    Integer somInt = new Integer(0);

    arr = input.split(";", -1);
    somInt = Integer.parseInt(arr[2].toString());

    arr[2] = ""+somInt; //storing non string value will give error 

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
```

Comment: The problem is now I have stored a Integer Value as a String

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayStoreException` is a *runtime* exception occurring when the type of the object that you are adding to an array is different than the type of object the array elements should be.

In your code, when assiging `somInt` to `arr[2]`, the array holds objects of type `String` whereas `someInt` is an `Integer`. You can assign a `String` as follows:

```
arr[2] = "" + somInt;
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` method of the `String` returns array of type `String`

and you are trying to store an integer value into this `String` type array on the line:

```
arr[2] = somInt;
```

you don't get compiler error as `String` extends `Object`. But you get runtime error, because upon execution `arr` becomes `String` type array.